# Why do I need a public modifier when overriding toString method?

Tags: java

Why do I need the public modifier for this instance method if I'm invoking it from within the same package?

```
   public String toString() {
    if (isOn()) {
        return "Speed is " + speed + ", color     is " + color
          + " and radius is " + radius;
    }
    else
        return "Fan is off. " + "Color is " + color
          + " and radius is " + radius;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you're actually trying to *override* `Object.toString()`.

Since that method is public, your accessibility must match.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are overriding it from [class] Object, and there it is public. You can't override and change access modifier - it won't be overriding.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to override the default `toString()` method. That method is public, therefore yours must also be public.

You're not allowed to change the visibility of any overridden functions of the parent classes, because all subclasses must be an instance of the parent class.

If you suddenly changed your `toString()` to private, your object isn't a valid `Object` anymore.

You may want to read this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle